# Redirecting subdomain to external dynamic url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, server, dns

I have a subdomain which I want to forward to a changing url for post requests.
The changing url can be obtained using a php script I have.

Example:

My subdomain:
subdomain.website.com

Php script:
website.com/getsite.php

I want the "subdomain.website.com" to redirect to whatever url is in the php script (it changes frequently), all this while forwarding post requests back and forth.

How can I achieve this? NodeJs? Php script? I am at a loss on how.

Comment: It sounds to me like you could use AJAX for your POST content and then do a regular redirect. Please explain the questions a bit better so I can elaborate

Comment: @YacoZaragoza  The end goal is for me to insert the subdomain into an application (which I have no control of) and have it redirect to the website which is outputted by the PHP script (something like otherwebsite.com:14000) which will receive post requests from the client

Answer (score 0):

use `$_SERVER ['HTTP_HOST']`. It is your domain/subdomain.

```
if ($_SERVER ['HTTP_HOST'] == 'subdomain.website.com') {

    Header ("Location: http://website.com/getsite.php");
    exit();

}
```

Comment: That won't work, any post request I do to subdomain.website.com will not get the response from the website in getsite.php